# jQuery find <br/> tags within div and add additional <br/> to each

Tags: jquery

How can I use jQuery to find all the `<br/>` tags within a div with class "post" and add an additional `<br/>` tag after each?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just guessing here but I would try using the .[after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) function like this

```
$('div.post br').after('<br/>');
```

Comment: nope. after adds elements after each found element by the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$('div.post br').each(function() {
    $(this).after($(document.createElement('br')));
});
```

But as an advice, you should avoid using `<br />` tags in `<div>` elements. Formatting should be done by CSS, for example you can add a `margin-after` to your `div` to have the same result.

Comment: Look at my answer, you don't need an each function.

Comment: jQuery will never stop to amaze me ;) But I personally will stick with this code, I find it clearer. Thanks for the comment though.